# Postgresql - Query the List of customers who have bought grocery at least once every month for 3 continuous months

Tags: sql, postgresql

With the following data

```
purchase_date                customer_id
2015-05-25 03:24:09+05:30 |  15 
2015-06-21 06:33:35+05:30 |  15
2015-07-02 02:03:32+05:30 |  17
2015-07-25 10:20:31+05:30 |  15
2015-07-25 10:20:31+05:30 |  12
2015-07-26 01:20:31+05:30 |  17
2015-08-26 03:24:09+05:30 |  17
2015-08-21 03:21:21+05:30 |  14
```

I want to get the list of customer_ids who have entries for once a month for 3 consecutive months.

I am using PostgreSQL 10.14

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve] and describe what you try to do?

Comment: Is it always 3 months or will you one day want 4 ?

Comment: This doesn't really look like a SQL request. You want us to help you finding an algorithm I guess? Or do you have one already and forgot to tell us? How far have you got with this problem? Please share your ideas. What exactly do you want us to do here?

Comment: a) Is there any customer in your example which fits your requirement (I cannot see one) b) What is if a customer has two entries in one month, but none in a following. Is the requirement to get 3 visits over three months? Or is it necessary that he has one visit per month? c) What is a month? Do you mean real calendar months or do you want to count fromt the first visit (maybe 25th to 25th?) In that case what about the 31st of january, does it goes into march or only to feb 28?

Comment: Here's a way if you think in "calendar months": select the distinct yyyy-mm and the customer id, then use LAG and LEAD to get the nextdate and previousdate month for any given row, then choose only those rows where the diff between this row date and previousdate is one month and diff between this row date and nextdate is one month

Comment: @CaiusJard it is at least three months. So if a customer purchase is made for three consecutive months I have to count it in.

Comment: I mean will one day your boss say "we arent gonna reward those 'one a month for 3 months people' now, because times are hard they only get the reward if they shop one a month for 6 months in a row!" - I ask because 3 is quite nice and easy with current, lag and lead - it's 3 options.. but if it's 4 months or 6 months then youre looking at sql that does run-length counting trying to find runs that are 6+.. and it's a bit more involved

Comment: @S-Man customer with id 15 matches the requirement here as it's purchase appears for may, june and july. If a customer makes purchase for 3 consecutive months at least once then it fits the requirement.

Comment: @CaiusJard I understand your point. It is going to be 3 months only for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e4f7d4fd3c97a96322c21b53110168f9)

```
SELECT
    customer_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        age(                                                -- 5
            month, 
                -- 4
            first_value(month) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        ) as months,
                -- 3
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT                                     -- 2
            date_trunc('month', purchase_date) as month,    -- 1
            customer_id
        FROM mytable
    ) s
) s
WHERE months = interval '2 months' and count = 3            -- 6
```

Examples to all steps can be seen in the fiddle linked above!

1. `date_trunc('month', ...)` normalizes the dates to the first of their actual month. So, we can build groups of dates in a month no matter what is the actual day
2. Using `DISTINCT` eliminates all tied records. So, if a customer had two records in the same month, these duplicates shouldn't be recognized anymore
3. Using the rolling [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html): In that case, the `COUNT()` recognizes only the current record and two rows before in a group. So, the first record of a customer_id group would return 1, the third - if available - would return 3.
4. Now, the `COUNT()` over rows is not enough. Because it can be, that we have the months 1, 3, 5, which are, obviously, no consecutive months. So, we need to now the first month of the rolling window. If it is two months before, we can be sure, that the window really contains 3 consecutive months: Two months ago, one month ago and the current month.
5. Calculate the difference between the first month of the window and the current month
6. Now we have a rolling window of max. 3 records. We now the difference of months from the current record to the first record of the group. We now need to filter the interesting records: We need a third record of a group (which ensures the "at least 3 months") but only those, which month difference is exactly 2, to ensure that the window does not contain a bigger range.

---

Additionally:

If you would mind to update to at least **Postgres 11**, you could leave out the steps 4 to 6, because it supports date ranges instead of rows for window functions. So, we don't need to handle the date range separately.

The result looks more handy, doesn't it?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6258c5cf3c8f0bac4a6ccae1b67b9510)

```
SELECT
    customer_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY month RANGE BETWEEN interval '2 months' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            date_trunc('month', purchase_date) as month,
            customer_id
        FROM mytable
    ) s
) s
WHERE count = 3
```

Comment: Thanks man for explaining in depth, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to customers and months.  Then simply use `lag()` -- once:

```
select distinct customer_id
from (select customer_id, date_trunc('month', purchase_date) as yyyymm,
             lag(date_trunc('month', purchase_date), 2) over (partition by customer_id order by min(purchase_date)) as prev2_yyyymm
      from t
      group by customer_id, date_trunc('month', purchase_date)
     ) t
where prev2_yyyymm = yyyymm - interval '2 month';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce the data to just months and customers:

```
WITH mc AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', purchase_date) mo, customer_id
  FROM t
)
```

Then add a CTE that uses analytics to get the prev and next mo:

```
WITH mc AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', purchase_date) mo, customer_id
  FROM t
), mcpn AS (
  SELECT 
    LAG(mo) OVER(partition by customer_id) as prevmo,
    LEAD(mo) OVER(partition by customer_id) as nextmo,
    mc.*
  FROM mc
)
```

Then select those where the prevmo, mo, nextmo are a month apart:

```
WITH mc AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', purchase_date) mo, customer_id
  FROM t
), mcpn AS (
  SELECT 
    LAG(mo) OVER(partition by customer_id) as prevmo,
    LEAD(mo) OVER(partition by customer_id) as nextmo,
    mc.*
  FROM mc
)
SELECT customer_id FROM mcpn WHERE AGE(prevmo, mo) = interval '1 month' AND AGE(mo, nextmo) = interval '1 month'
```